# Download multiple files from SFTP server as a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, sftp

I am trying to create a `Jenkins job` which will pull multiple files from a `SFTP` server to local machine.

By using `ssh2easy` plugin in `Jenkins` i am able to connect to `SFTP` server and pull single file as shown below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I found using the linux command line tools sftp/scp in a shell build step convenient for that.

Comment: `scp` will work only in case of password-less connections which i am not using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSH2Easy plugin with following configuration in job:

- remoteFile: /remoteFolderPath/*
- localFolder: jobs/jobName/workspace/
- fileName: temp/

localFolder is path to job workspace - this depends on jenkins configuration where workspace is located

fileName must end with "/" and the folder must exist in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell build step with curl.

curl command to use:
`curl --insecure sftp://username:urlencodedPassword@somedomain.com`

Be aware that username/password have to be at the beginning of the domain name, separated by an @.

Comment: What encoding to use for the `urlencodedPassword`?