# How can I transfer files from a remote Linux server to artifactory

Tags: linux, jenkins, sftp, artifactory

How can I write a script in Jenkins ( have a linux node) that will allow me to transfer a file, for e.g ***sample.txt*** which is present in the remote linux server to the artifactory ( Jfrog).

I am new to the whole SFTP from CLI since usually, I have done through the WinSCP UI and that too from my local to a remote server, so any pointers on where to get started will be helpful as well

Comment: Where seem to be many question about Jenkins SFTP download. First two hits: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62030989/850848 + https://stackoverflow.com/q/44202172/850848 – Did you check those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looking to deploy artifacts only through the Jenkins job, then you can use the
[DeployArtifact](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact) REST API, create a UNIX script based on your requirement, and then execute the same through the [Execute shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374998/run-a-command-shell-in-jenkins) option from the Jenkins job.

As a side note, if you are looking to deploy the artifacts that exists on the Jenkins VM to the Artifactory repository, then you can make use of the **rtUpload** method. You can refer to the JFrog wiki page [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-UploadingandDownloadingFiles) for more details with an example on the same.

Comment: Adding to this comment - I'd recommend using the JFrog CLI for this purpose. The usage is very straight forward: `jf rt upload <local-path> <remote-path>`. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles

Comment: @Pavan the tUpload method did work, but still have to figure out a way to get the files from the remote server to the workspace in the first palce.